# Why can't Rails find '../javascripts/application.js'?

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I just updated my Rails application to 5.0.0.rc1 and it is now not able to load my assets. The initial error claimed that I need a manifest.rb file in assets/config. I did not have this folder so I created it along with the manifest.rb file. Here is my manifest.rb file:

```
//= link ../javascripts/application.js
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .sass
//= link_tree ../javascripts .js
//= link_tree ../images
```

And now I am getting this:

> ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file '../javascripts/application.js' under '/Users/Clover/Desktop/Code/myroomies/app/assets/config'):
>       4:   RoomiesApp
>       5:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
>       6:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application.css.sass', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => 'reload' %>
>       7:   <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => 'reload' %>
>       8:
>       9:   
>      10:

app/assets/config/manifest.js:1
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1555946743671048113_70305755306180'
  Rendering /Users/Clover/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /Users/Clover/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/Clover/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (3.8ms)
  Rendering /Users/Clover/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/Clover/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.6ms)
  Rendering /Users/Clover/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /Users/Clover/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/Clover/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.rc1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (60.2ms)

My application.js file is definitely at that route as far as I can tell.

My application is currently running in Heroku with no problems. So I cloned the repo directly from Heroku. It didn't have the assets/config folder, but still seems to be working fine. I understand there is a difference between production and development environments, but I am not still not clear on how to toggle properly between the two. What am I missing here?

Comment: @RichardPeck I just changed the first line '//= link ../javascripts/application.js' to '//= link application.js' in the manifest.rb file. It seems as if the manifest file already knows to look in the ../javascripts folder for the file making it unnecessary to specify it's relative path.